# How to weight samples in a subsample of a stratified sample?

Tags: estimation, sampling, estimators, stratification, poststratification

Suppose I'm first interested in computing the percentage of people in a certain town with brown eyes. However, due to some constraints I end up with the following stratified sampling set up:

$$N = 1000$$
$$N_{male} = 500$$
$$N_{female} = 500$$
$$n_{male} = 75$$
$$n_{female} = 25$$

I see that 25 men and 10 women in the sample have brown eyes, so using the Horvitz-Thompson estimator I calculate:

$$p(\text{brown eyes}) = (1/N)\sum(y_{i} / \tau_{i}) = (1/1000) * (25 * (500/75) + 10 * (500/25)) = 0.366$$
$$\text{where } \tau_{i} \text{ is the inclusion probability}$$

However, now I become interested in the probability that a *child* has brown eyes. I want to re-use my earlier sample to save costs, so I look at the existing data I have and find that I previously sampled 30 male children (10 brown eyes) and 12 female children (4 brown eyes). I also find the population counts for children in the town.

Is it valid to then use the setup below? Or am I missing something?

$$N_{children} = 400$$
$$N_{male\_children} = 200$$
$$N_{female\_children} = 200$$
$$n_{male\_children} = 30$$
$$n_{female\_children} = 12$$

$$p(\text{child has brown eyes}) = (1/N_{children})\sum(y_{i} / \tau_{i}) = (1/400) * (10 * (200/30) + 4 * (200/12)) = 0.333$$

Comment: You need to change the notation / the formula in the last expression a little bit, but that's pretty much what post-stratification is about. Are you sure this is not a homework problem of some kind? If it is, you need to tag your post `self-study`. (Most instructors' hearts are warmed when they see their students ask the homework questions on SE.)

Comment: thanks for the response. This isn't a homework question, I'm working on a small consulting project, but am a bit new to sampling theory. The setup here is a very simplified version of the "real" project I'm doing, but I thought it was easier to ask it in this format rather than explaining the more complex setup

Comment: : shrugs : more complex situations may call for entirely different solutions.

Comment: I mean, of course it might. But I'm just trying to understand some of the basics so don't think that's relevant here.